# Removing unnecessary models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have multiple models (up to 20 models) from which I want to load to the viewer only two at time. Is there a way to clear the viewer or remove loaded models before loading new models.

Currently I first hide all the models.

```
function hideAllModels() {
  for (var i = 0; i < loadedModels.length; i++) {
    var instanceTree = loadedModels[i].getData().instanceTree;
    var rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();
    var vm = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VisibilityManager(viewer.impl, loadedModels[i]);
    vm.hide(rootId);
    vm.setNodeOff(rootId, true);
  }
}
```

Then show the ones I want.

```
var vm = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VisibilityManager(viewer.impl, viewer.model);
vm.setNodeOff(rootId, false);
vm.show(rootId);
```

This hiding and showing is very slow with multiple models. Also then searching through the loaded models for individual objects is very slow. Is the only way to always initiliaze the whole viewer before loading/showing the two models? I tried using also getState() and restoreState(), but this only saves the view. It does not clear the models from the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [aggregate sample](https://forge.autodesk.io/) implements this feature, you can find the source code at [this github](https://github.com/leefsmp/forge) ([direct link](https://github.com/leefsmp/forge/blob/master/src/client/Components/Viewer/extensions/Viewing.Extension.ModelTransformer/Viewing.Extension.ModelTransformer.js#L384)), but I'm copying below:

```
deleteModel (model, fireEvent = true) {
 delete this.modelCollection[model.modelId]
 if(Object.keys(this.modelCollection).length === 0){
   this.firstModelLoaded = null
 }
 if(fireEvent) {
   this.emit('model.delete', model)
 }
 this._viewer.impl.unloadModel(model)
}
```